# i want update one column in sql on basis of id i.e. insert id values in the my new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want update  one column in sql on basis of id i.e. insert id values in the my new column

tb1

```
id1  name1
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

TB2

```
ID2 name id1 name1
1    X    1    null
2    Y    2     null
3    Z     1     null
```

what i wanted  update TB2 name1 column on the basis of id1

Comment: Which **`RDBMS`** ?

Comment: To be clear: Is it MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `update` with `join`

```
update t2 set t2.nam1 = t1.name1 from tb2 t2
join tb1 t1 on  t1.id1 = t2.id1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update TB2 SET TB2.name1 = tb1.name1 FROM tb1 ,TB2 WHERE tb1.id1 = TB2.id1
```

try this code in MS SQl